# F# Convert String Array to String

Tags: string, f#

With C#, I can use `string.Join("", lines)` to convert string array to string.
What can I do to do the same thing with F#?

### ADDED

I need to read lines from a file, do some operation, and then concatenate all the lines into a single line.

When I run this code

```
open System.IO
open String

let lines = 
  let re = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"#(\d+)")
  [|for line in File.ReadAllLines("tclscript.do") ->
      re.Replace(line.Replace("{", "{{").Replace("}", "}}").Trim(), "$1", 1)|]

let concatenatedLine = String.Join("", lines)

File.WriteAllLines("tclscript.txt", concatenatedLine)
```

I got this error

```
error FS0039: The value or constructor 'Join' is not defined
```

I tried this code `let concatenatedLine = lines |> String.concat ""` to get this error

```
error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    string []    
but here has type
    string
```

### Solution

```
open System.IO
open System 

let lines = 
  let re = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"#(\d+)")
  [|for line in File.ReadAllLines("tclscript.do") ->
      re.Replace(line.Replace("{", "{{").Replace("}", "}}"), "$1", 1) + @"\n"|]

let concatenatedLine = String.Join("", lines)
File.WriteAllText("tclscript.txt", concatenatedLine)
```

and this one also works.

```
let concatenatedLine = lines |> String.concat ""
```

Comment: Why doesn't that work in F#? It's part of the .NET framework.

Comment: `String.Join(",", [1; 2; 3])` works just fine in F#.

Comment: @Daniel : I elaborated my question. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Are you simply missing `open System` to access the String class? - Also, what is `re`?

Comment: @wmeyer : adding `open System` doesn't work. I added the re part for complete code.

Comment: See @desco's answer. I think you need `WriteAllText`.

Comment: @prosseek: Interesting that you accepted someone else's answer to your previous question, but you're using my code. :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

use String.concat ?

```
["a"; "b"]
|> String.concat ", " // "a, b"
```

**EDITED:**

in your code replace *File.WriteAllLines* with *File.WriteAllText*

```
let concatenatedLine = 
    ["a"; "b"]
    |> String.concat ", "

open System.IO

let path = @"..."
File.WriteAllText(path, concatenatedLine)
```

Comment: let concatenatedLine = lines |> String.concat "" doesn't seem to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Copied from an fsi console window:

```
> open System;;
> let stringArray = [| "Hello"; "World!" |];;

val stringArray : string [] = [|"Hello"; "World!"|]

> let s = String.Join(", ", stringArray);;

val s : string = "Hello, World!"

>
```

EDIT:

Using String.Join from the .NET framework class library is, of course, less idiomatic than using String.concat from the F# core library.  I can only presume that is why someone voted my answer down, since that person did not extend the courtesy of explaining the vote.

The reason I posted this answer, as I mentioned in my comment below, is that the use of String.concat in all of the other answers might mislead casual readers into thinking that String.Join is not at all available in F#.

Comment: Why the downvote?  None of the answers gave an example of using the framework Join method, so readers might assume, incorrectly, that this is not possible.

Comment: +1. Helped me out whilst I'm trying to get my head around a functional language anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

```
List.ofSeq "abcd" |> List.toArray |> (fun s -> System.String s) |> printfn "%A"
List.ofSeq "abcd" |> List.toArray |> (fun s -> new System.String(s)) |> printfn "%A"
```